# iOS7 Local Notification for app polling server for new data of interest running in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm just wondering if using `Local Notification` is possible for my app instead of `Push Notification`.

My app get data from my sever via the server's API. It's a small social network for soccer player. I'd like the app to notify the user when the user's friends post a pickup game in the user's city.

Is it possible for the app to run a background process to poll the server for new pickup game in the city say every 10-15 minute, when there is a new pickup game, it sends a notification to the device?

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid push notifications? It seems like the flow of the app is a book example of what push notifications are used for. It would be optimal for your app to react only when there is a game available, instead of constantly checking and getting (mostly) "no new games" messages. As a side note, it is not possible to have your app running in the background to do that check every 15 minutes.

Comment: Well, Local Notification is easier and quicker to implement. I'm trying to get a MVP for client to see so I thought I'd go that route.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want to do is implement the iOS7 background multi-tasking API and perform *background fetches*. Decent tutorial here: http://hayageek.com/ios-background-fetch/

You don't have control over when the operating system allows you to wake up in the background to perform the fetch, but during this operation you could poll your server and if new data was present use that to show a local notification.

Comment: Also, be aware that with this method you won't get a chance to check if your app isn't running in the background - such as after a device restart or as a result of memory pressure, for example

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in the way that you're thinking. When a local notification is fired, you cannot execute any custom code unless (or until) your app is actually active. If the user does indeed tap on your notification in notification center, you can get the notification info from your application delegate from either the launch options in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` if your app is starting up or from `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` if your app was already running but in the background.

If you're okay with this only working while the app is actually in the foreground, then you can set whatever timers or notifications you want.

Comment: Sounds like you've got what he wants to do backwards - he wants to ask the server for information while in the background, and if there is information display a local notification. This is entirely possible.

Comment: It would be much easier with push notifications which would allow you to trigger a background fetch but he doesn't want to use those. Background fetches on their own could work as long as time interval is not an issue since there is no guaranteed time in between calls.

Comment: Except incorporating push notifications into the mix involves much more work by comparison, either writing all the server-side push code or incorporating a third party to handle the pushes..